# refresh view controller at the end of table in bottom in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uirefreshcontrol

> Blockquote
>   How to set the position of refresh controller in iOS at the end of table.
>   After last data refresh

controller must be shown

Comment: I dont really get what you mean. Maybe rewrite your question?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it will be clear what the question is.

Comment: what is refresh controller? :O

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return arrData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    if (arrData.count==indexPath.row+1) {
        //call reload method & reload tableView
    }
    ...
}
```